# How to delay of AMQ shutdown until after Camel Route shutdown in PaxExam Test

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, pax-exam

i am running

- SerivceMix 6.1.2
- Camel 2.16.3
- PaxExam 4.10
- ActiveMQ 5.12.3 embedded in ServiceMix as a feature by @Configure to simulate the external one

When i test my Camel routes having AMQ endpoints and the test method finishes, the AMQ is shutdown earlier than the Camel routes. Causing the routes endpoints throwing a lot of lost connection exceptions, especially when there are inflights.
The start level of the AMQ is much lower than my routes. How can i ensure the shutdown sequence:
- route, 
- amq, 
- servicemix
?

Answer (score 0):

Specify to have your Camel route (or test bundle) depend on the ActiveMQ broker service. When the bundles are being shutdown, they will be shutdown in reverse dependency order and the broker (which doesn't depend on any of your coded services) should shutdown towards the end.

```
<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" 
class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
 ...
</bean>
```

Updated:

1. Add a reference to your blueprint file on the service providing the broker
2. Add a 'depends-on' attribute to your Camel route
3. This allows OSGi to deterministically configure the proper startup and shutdown based on explicit dependency vs arbitrary (what you have now) or a number-ordered convention.

   ```
   <camelContext depends-on="activemq-broker">
   </camelContext>

   <reference id="activemq-broker" 
       availability="mandatory" 
       timeout="5000"
       interface="org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService" 
       filter="(service.pid=org.apache.servicemix.activemq.service)"/>
   ```

Comment: Hello Matt, if i specify a dependency to the broker. Then i need a broker service in LIVE also, right? Which i want to avoid, for switching to pure Karaf later and having the ActiveMQ on a different server anyway.

Comment: Gotcha, try this instead-- depend on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory bean and then in the connection factory bean for the test specify vm:// .. for embedded test broker.  Then production you can swap it out for the real url. Note-- make sure you call start() stop() if you use the recommended activemq-pool connection factory.

Comment: Mmh, i am not quite sure what you mean. My "proxy" bundle using the ActiveMQConnectionFactory depends on activemq-client feature, this is configured in blueprint including start/stop attributes.
My test broker is configured by the default .cfg file of ServiceMix and the activemq.xml (allowing tcp, vm, stomp).
I reconfigured my proxy bundle to use vm:// but that changed nothing regarding shutdown behaviour.

Comment: Updating the answer.. b/c it'll exceed character limit

Comment: Hello Matt, if i add the reference+depends-on then my reactor is not exiting and the VM is closed by failsafe after a timeout.
The good thing is that there are no exceptions because of broken ActiveMQ connections :-). The depends-on/references work fine.
The bad is i have this ugly dependency in my context which is not needed for LIVE. Later on we will switch to a newer Karaf w/o embedded ActiveMQ broker anyway.
I think i have to shut down and start each route by hand for each test method.

Comment: @KarstenB glad to hear that helped =)  Sounds like you are pretty close and might just be one hung thread away from having clean shutdown. FWIW-- Karaf+Camel+ActiveMQ should shutdown cleanly for you. Happy hacking.

Comment: Thanx, Matt! BR Karsten